# Problems loading Google Maps API callback script in Webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, webpack

I have a function `initMap()` that is supposed to be called when the Google Maps API has finished loading. This function manages all of the settings for the map I use in my web-app.

`initMap()` lives in a file called `init-map.js`.

I'm migrating to Webpack, so `init-map.js` is now being included in `index.js` using `require('./scripts/init-map.js`.

I'm getting an error `InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function`, but when I load `init-map.js` using its own `<script>` tag, I don't get the error.

**Causes error:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script src="bundle.js"></script> <!-- init-map.js is required in this file -->
    </head>
    <body>
        ....
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Works without issue:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="./scripts/init-map.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ....
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't understand how to make `initMap()` available for the Google Maps API when it makes the callback.

I would also prefer to have the `init-map.js` managed within `index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because the bundler changes the name of your initMap function to something like a single letter, e.g. `e` or `f`.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your calling part. Is it throwing 404 errors? on inspect element -> Network

Try using from "./scripts/init-map.js" to "/scripts/init-map.js" or "scripts/init-map.js"

Comment: The script is loading correctly in both cases. There are no 404 errors.

Comment: can you share init-map.js code? Can you see any errors on console?